# atexit considered harmful?

Tags: c, c99, atexit

Are there inherent dangers in using `atexit` in large projects such as libraries?

If so, what is it about the technical nature behind `atexit` that may lead to problems in larger projects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main reason I would avoid using `atexit` in libraries is that any use of it involves global state. A good library should avoid having global state.

However, there are also other technical reasons:

1. Implementations are only required to support a small number (32, I think) of `atexit` handlers. After that, it's possible that all calls to `atexit` fail, or that they succeed or fail depending on resource availability. Thus, you have to deal with what to do if you can't register your `atexit` handler, and there might not be any good way to proceed.
2. Interaction of `atexit` with `dlopen` or other methods of loading libraries dynamically is not defined. A library which has registered `atexit` handlers cannot safely be unloaded, and the ways different implementations deal with this situation can vary.
3. Poorly written `atexit` handlers could have interactions with one another, or just bad behaviors, that prevent the program from properly exiting. For instance, if an `atexit` handler attempts to obtain a lock that's held in another thread and that can't be released due to the state at the time `exit` was called.

Comment: "Since glibc 2.2.3, atexit() (and on_exit(3)) can be used within a shared library to establish functions that are called when the shared library is unloaded." Taken from `man atexit`. 
However, I am not sure, whether the same behavior is enforced on other C libs. So, if you're targeting glibc solely, this doesn't apply to you.

Answer (score 1):

Secure CERT has an entry about `atexit` when not used correctly:

*ENV32-C. All atexit handlers must return normally*

https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/ENV32-C.+All+atexit+handlers+must+return+normally

Comment: So the problems typically arise when a function passed to `atexit` has the potential to call `exit` or otherwise not return normally?

Comment: The C++ equivalent of this bug actually exists somewhere (I forget where) in the LLVM codebase. They have a destructor that calls `exit`...